# RavenDB query using or statement

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have two dates (DeliveryDate and EmptyDate) fields on an document which i want to query using the same date. So if i query for 2016-04-04 and this date is in either DeliveryDate OR EmptyDate the query should return the document.

Beside these to fields i also severale of other filters so a query could look like this:

```
    var query = _documentSession.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Order, OrdersIndexFields>()
                .UsingDefaultOperator(QueryOperator.And);

query.WhereBetweenOrEqual(OrdersIndexFields.DeliveryInfo_DeliveryDateUtc,
predicate.LocalDeliveryFrom.Value,
predicate.LocalDeliveryTo.Value);

query.OrElse().WhereBetweenOrEqual(OrdersIndexFields.EmptyOrderDoneDate,
predicate.LocalDeliveryFrom.Value,
predicate.LocalDeliveryTo.Value);

query.WhereEquals(OrdersIndexFields.Status, predicate.Status);

query
    .Skip(0).Take(1024)
    .ToArray();
```

The problem is that the OrElse() method i'm using does not work as expected. The above query returns too many results.

How do i write a proper OR statement in a RavenDB query?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the Lucene query API, rather than the standard Raven LINQ query API?

Comment: @JudahHimango i'm using joined collection fields from my index to filter and as far i can see it is not possible to do linq filtering on index fields so i have to stick with the Lucene query API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After i don't know how many hours used to fixed this i stumpled over this [RavenDB OpenClause example](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/querying/lucene/how-to-use-not-operator). I have been googling after RavenDB inner statement and then it turns out RavenDB calls them subclause :D. Any how i solved my issue.

So my code above now works using Open and End subclause methods on the RavenDB DocumentQuery API:

```
query.OpenSubclause();
query.WhereBetweenOrEqual(OrdersIndexFields.DeliveryInfo_DeliveryDateUtc,
predicate.LocalDeliveryFrom.Value,
predicate.LocalDeliveryTo.Value);

query.OrElse().WhereBetweenOrEqual(OrdersIndexFields.EmptyOrderDoneDate,
predicate.LocalDeliveryFrom.Value,
predicate.LocalDeliveryTo.Value);
query.CloseSubclause();
```

This adds parentheses around my "inner or statement" in the lucene query. So before the query looked like this:

```
DeliveryInfo_DeliveryDateUtc:[2016-03-31T22:00:00.0000000Z TO 2016-04-27T22:00:00.0000000Z] OR EmptyOrderDoneDate:[2016-03-31T22:00:00.0000000Z TO 2016-04-27T22:00:00.0000000Z] AND Status:None
```

And after adding open end subclause it looks like this giving me the expected result:

```
(DeliveryInfo_DeliveryDateUtc:[2016-03-31T22:00:00.0000000Z TO 2016-04-27T22:00:00.0000000Z] OR EmptyOrderDoneDate:[2016-03-31T22:00:00.0000000Z TO 2016-04-27T22:00:00.0000000Z]) AND Status:None
```